# Unable to use Google Play Service in Samsung SM-A7009

Tags: samsung, google-play-services

I have a Samsung SM-A7009 with SDK API version 21. The device (SM-A7009) is targeted for the Chinese market, where Gapps service is usually not accessible. Gapps are not installed by default on this device. I have successfully installed Google Service Framework, Google Account Manager, and Google Play Service as a normal third-party app (not system apps). But Google Play Service setting can't run with the following error from `logcat`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610): FATAL EXCEPTION: [bif] processing com.google.android.gms.GOOGLE_SETTINGS_OPERATION
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610): Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 6610
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610): java.lang.SecurityException: You need MANAGE_USERS permission to: query user
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at android.os.IUserManager$Stub$Proxy.getUserInfo(IUserManager.java:629)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at android.os.UserManager.getUserInfo(UserManager.java:528)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at android.os.UserManager.isManagedProfile(UserManager.java:482)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at xyc.a(:com.google.android.gms:2071)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at ydc.f(:com.google.android.gms:88)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at ydc.d(:com.google.android.gms:84)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.settings.TapAndPaySettingsIntentOperation.b(:com.google.android.gms:21)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at gzl.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms:96)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at bie.run(:com.google.android.gms:1873)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6610):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
V/ApplicationPolicy( 1053): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.google.android.gms.ui
W/ActivityManager( 1053):   Force finishing activity com.google.android.gms/.app.settings.GoogleSettingsActivity
```

Did the ROM have done special settings to prevent Gapps from running on this device? How can I run Google Play Service without root, also without flashing a new custom ROM?

The following list is more information about the device.

```
[ril.product_code]: [Not Active]
[ro.build.product]: [a7ltectc]
[ro.product.board]: [MSM8939]
[ro.product.brand]: [samsung]
[ro.product.cpu.abi2]: [armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [armeabi-v7a]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist32]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist64]: []
[ro.product.cpu.abilist]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.device]: [a7ltectc]
[ro.product.locale.language]: [zh]
[ro.product.locale.region]: [CN]
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [samsung]
[ro.product.model]: [SM-A7009]
[ro.product.name]: [a7ltectc]
[ro.product_ship]: [true]
```

Answer (score 0):

My sympathy to all who imported devices from China but want to use GAPPS...

Found this [CWM recovery](http://dl.muzisoft.com/soft/recovery/muzisoft-a7009-cwm-recovery-6.0.5.1-cn(0205).tar) for the exact model. Not verified by me but members from local forums reported fine.

Unlock bootloader with [CROM](http://www.muzisoft.com/soft/90404.html) first (download page in Chinese).

Flash this recovery with Odin, boot into it, make a nandroid backup (just in case) and install a compatible GAPPS package (uninstall what you've installed first), no root required. You can also easily obtain root with it when needed later.